# Difference between Gnu sort -k2 and -k2,2

Tags: sort

```
less file.txt

01 Joe x
02 Marie y
03 Albert p
04 Dave k
```

I want to sort by column 2. However both of the following commands give same output. It would be great to know what is the difference between using -k2 and -k2,2.

`less file.txt | sort -k2` and `less file.txt | sort -k2,2`

Output:

```
03 Albert p
04 Dave k
01 Joe x
02 Marie y
```

Comment: It is not a linux command. It is running on linux (sometimes). However it is a Gnu command. The OS that you are running is a Gnu/Linux. Linux is the kernel, Gnu is the essential user-land parts, together they are Gnu/Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification after the comma defines a `stop position` (which defaults to the `end of the line`)

`man 1 sort`:

> `-k`, `--key=KEYDEF` sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> KEYDEF is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]` for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.

---

For example, consider an input `file.txt`:

```
03 Albert p
04 Albert a
```

- If sorted using `-k2`, `Albert a` would be placed before `Albert p`
- By using `-k2,2`, the third key will be ignored when sorting

---

or a different example:

```
03 Albert p
04 Aave k
```

It is possible to sort by the first character of the second key using `-k2,2.2`:

```
$ sort -k2,2.2 file.txt
03 Albert p
04 Aave k
```

- If `-k2` were used, `Aa` would be sorted before `Al`